# Starting a site from scratch after running "drush sql-drop"

Tags: 8, database, drush

In drupal 7 I was able to just do a **drush sql-drop** and then visit the site and it would throw the install screen. But in Drupal 8 I'm getting an error when I do a drush sql-drop when going back to the site. Are there static files I need to also delete in Drupal 8 along with doing a sql-drop?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your **settings.php** file is still persisting after the command. Removing it should prompt you for installation on root request.

```
# Replace with location of settings.php file
settings_file=sites/default/settings.php
drush -y sql-drop && rm "$settings_file"
```